# Redirect process output - I am getting nulls

Tags: c#, console

I have a program that parses a txt file and produces output like this:

[image]

As you can see, it works. However, it does not work if you execute the "map-server.exe" with the args as a one line (i.e. without the cd command).

I am now trying to use this inside a C# winform app.

I want to execute this "map-server.exe" and pass an arg of a *.txt file of my choice and re-direct the output a richtextbox on my app.

So, I tried the following:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Test : Form
    {
        private string currentDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ParseScript("jobmaster.txt");
        }

        private void ParseScript(string fileName)
        {
            Process p = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/C cd /D " + currentDir + "\\script_checker_bin && map-server.exe --script-check "+ fileName,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    ErrorDialog = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                SynchronizingObject = this
            };
            p.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => UpdateLog(s, e);
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }

        private void UpdateLog(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != e.Data && e.Data.Length > 0)
                this.richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch the app, `e.Data` is always `null`. Any idea why this doesn't work?

My app compiles to `Test.exe` and this is where all the files are:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `map-server.exe --script-check jobmaster.txt > output.txt` on the commandline? Does it create output.txt with the output in it? Or does it still print on the screen?

Comment: That will not be a problem, the issue for me is; If I run the command as a one line, e.g. `C:\>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\Test\bin\Debug\script_checker_bin\map-server.exe --script-check C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\Test\bin\Debug\script_checker_bin\jobmaster.txt` I get an error from the "map-server.exe" application `[Fatal Error]: File not found: conf/inter-server.conf` (as if the app doesn't know where it is executing from)

Comment: Are you sure that won't be a problem? I'm asking because I notice it's printing in color, so I wonder if it's using some non-standard method of doing that which isn't going into stdout properly. Redirecting it to a file would be a good test.

Comment: Try using the WorkingDirectory property of ProcessStartInfo to specify the working directory.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Good point, I tried that via command line and the output is still showing on my cmd window and a 0 byte `output.txt` file was generated. @phoog - Tried that and did not work for me.

Comment: Actually, your sample screenshot looks like an error - maybe the output is going into stderr, not stdout. You could try `2> output.txt` to verify that, and/or try handling `ErrorDataReceived`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Good catch! I tried `2> output.txt` and the output from my screenshot was on that file. http://i.imgur.com/lxVQ43x.png. However, I am not able to replicate this by handling `ErrorDataReceived` (still empty / null on my c# app)

Comment: Did you `BeginErrorReadLine`? You should also probably add a `WaitForExit` afterwards.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thank you very much. I got it working. http://i.imgur.com/kWDz0Pg.png - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NzVtZnd2. `WaitForExit` made my app hang and the form would not launch